# lower resolution image loading slower than the same image in high resolution

Tags: php

I'm making a website where a user can upload images, and rotate the images.
I also resize the images 2 times with php to have 2 sizes of the image (depending where it is displayed).

I tried to lower the resolution of jpg images by setting the third peremeter of imagejpeg to 84 instead of 100, but the weird thing is that the lower resolution images are taking the same time, and sometimes longer to load than the same image with a high resolution.
(I tested it on pingdom multiple times.)

Here's a link to a page with high resolution images. http://9typestest.com/ahblick3/cat4.php?cat=1530016402548
and the next link is to a image gallery with the same images but lower resolution
http://9typestest.com/ahblick3/cat4.php?cat=1530018903821.

This is the php i use to resize the images.
For higher resolution i replace 100 in third peremter of imagjpeg with 84

```
 if(in_array($filee,$images)){

    //rotate image
    $degrees = -(float)$deg;
    $source_properties = getimagesize($filetl);
    $image_type = $source_properties[2]; 
    if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filetl);
        $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
        imagejpeg($rotate,$filetl,100);
        imagedestroy($source);
        imagedestroy($rotate);
    }elseif($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG){
        echo'yesyesyesn';
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($filetl);
        $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
        imagepng($rotate,$filetl,9);
        imagedestroy($source);
        imagedestroy($rotate);
    }
        //see how much to resize image first time
            if($source_properties[0]>10000){
                $final_w = 9.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>7500&&$source_properties[0]<10000){
                $final_w = 7;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>6000&&$source_properties[0]<7500){
                $final_w = 5.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>4500&&$source_properties[0]<6000){
                $final_w = 4;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>3000&&$source_properties[0]<4500){
                $final_w = 2.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>1500&&$source_properties[0]<2999){
                $final_w = 1.4;
            }else{
                $final_w = 1;
            }
            //resize image first time
            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($filetl);  
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagejpeg($target_layer,'dest2/'.$filename,100);
            imagejpeg($target_layer,'destp/'.$filename.'.html',100);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )  {  
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromgif($filetl);
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagegif($target_layer,'dest2/'.$filename,100);
            imagegif($target_layer,'p/'.$filename.'.html',100);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefrompng($filetl);
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagepng($target_layer,'dest2/'.$filename,9);
            imagepng($target_layer,'destp/'.$filename.'.html',9);
            }
        $filen = time();

        //resize watermark image 
        $source_properties2 = getimagesize('out/water3.png');
        if($target_width > $target_height){
            $target_width = $target_height * 0.45;
            $target_height = $target_width * 0.45;
        }else{
            $target_width = $target_width * 0.45;
            $target_height = $target_width * 0.45;
        }
        $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng( 'out/water3.png' ); 

        $targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor( $target_width, $target_height );   
        imagealphablending( $targetImage, false );
        imagesavealpha( $targetImage, true );
        imagecopyresampled( $targetImage, $srcImage, 
            0, 0, 
            0, 0, 
        $target_width,$target_height, $source_properties2[0],$source_properties2[1] );
        imagepng(  $targetImage, 'out/water4.png', 9 );

        //creat a watermark on the image
        function watermark_image($target, $wtrmrk_file, $newcopy) {
            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wtrmrk_file);
            imagealphablending($watermark, true);
            imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
            $source_properties2 = getimagesize($target);
            $image_type2 = $source_properties2[2];
            if( $image_type2 == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {  
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
            }elseif( $image_type2 == IMAGETYPE_GIF )  {
                $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
            }elseif( $image_type2 == IMAGETYPE_PNG )  {
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
            }                   
            $img_w = imagesx($img);
            $img_h = imagesy($img);
            $wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);
            $wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);
            $dst_x = ($img_w / 2) - ($wtrmrk_w / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
            $dst_y = ($img_h / 2) - ($wtrmrk_h / 2); // For centering the watermark on any image
            imagecopy($img, $watermark, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
            imagejpeg($img, $newcopy, 100);
            imagedestroy($img);
            imagedestroy($watermark);
        }
        $logo = 'out/water4.png';
            if(watermark_image('dest2/'.$filename,$logo, 'dest/'.$filename)){
                echo'big yes';
            }else{
                echo 'big no';
            }


        //see how much to resize image second time
        $source_properties = getimagesize('dest/'.$filename);
        $filesize = filesize('dest/'.$filename);
        $filesize /= 1000;
            if($source_properties[0]>3500){
                $final_w = 8.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>2999&&$source_properties[0]<3500){
                $final_w = 7.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>2499&&$source_properties[0]<3000){
                $final_w = 6.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>1999&&$source_properties[0]<2500){
                $final_w = 5.5;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>1499&&$source_properties[0]<2000){
                $final_w = 4.6;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>999&&$source_properties[0]<1500){
                $final_w = 3.1;
            }elseif($source_properties[0]>500&&$source_properties[0]<1000){
                $final_w = 1.2;
            }else{
                $final_w = 1;
            }

            $image_type = $source_properties[2]; 

            // resize image second time
            if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromjpeg('dest/'.$filename);  
            //$target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id,$source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagejpeg($target_layer,'sdest/'.$filename,100);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )  {  
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromgif('dest/'.$filename);
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagegif($target_layer,'sdest/'.$filename,100);
            }
            elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
            $image_resource_id = imagecreatefrompng('dest/'.$filename);
            $target_width = $source_properties[0] /$final_w;
            $target_height = $source_properties[1] / $final_w;
            $target_layer=imagecreatetruecolor($target_width,$target_height);
            imagecopyresampled($target_layer,$image_resource_id,0,0,0,0,$target_width,$target_height, $source_properties[0],$source_properties[1]);
            imagepng($target_layer,'sdest/'.$filename,9);
            }
    }
```

Comment: To confirm, the time you're talking about consists of compressing/resizing the image and then displaying it, not the difference of simply displaying a smaller image? Have you confirmed the difference in filesizes?

Comment: The difference is when displaying the image, compressing/resizing is already done before. also i checked the filesize differences, and the file with lower resolution is about 3.5 times smaller, BTW thanks for the quick reply